# Python application communicating with a web server? Ideas?

Tags: python, http, sockets

I'm looking for a bit of web development advice. I'm fairly new to the area but I'm sure there are some gurus out there willing to part with some wisdom.

Objective: I'm interested in controlling a Python application on my computer from my personal web hosted site. I know, this question has been asked several times before but in each case the requirements were a bit different from my own. To reduce the length of this post I'll summarize my objective in a few bullet points:

- Personal site is hosted by a web hosting company
- Site uses HTML, PHP, MySQL, Python and JavaScript, the majority of everything is coded by me from the ground up
- An application that is coded in Python will run on a PC within my home and will communicate with an Arduino board
- The app will receive commands from the internet to control actuation via the Arduino, and will transmit sensor data back to the site (such as temperature)
- Looking for the communication to be bi-directional, fast and secure
- Securing the connection between site and Python app would be most ideal
- I'm not looking to connect to the Python application directly, the web server must serve as the 'middle man'

So far I've considered HTTP Post and HTML forms, using sockets (Python app would run as a web server), an IRC bot and reading/writing to a text file stored on the web server.

I was also hoping to have a way to communicate with the Python app without needing to refresh the webpage, perhaps using AJAX or JavaScipt? Maybe with Flash?

Is there something I'm not considering? I feel like I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking out loud for how I would start out with this. First, regarding the website itself, you can just use what's easiest to you, or to the environment you're in. For example, a basic PHP page will do just fine, but if you can get a site running in Python as well, I'd prefer using the same language all over.

That said, I'm not sure why you would need to use a hosted website? Given that you're already forced to have a externally accessible PC at home for the communication, why not run a webserver on that directly (Apache, Nginx, or even something like CherryPy should do)? That webserver can then communicate with the python process that is running to control your Arduino (by using e.g. Python's [`xmlrpclib`](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html)). If you would run things via the hosting company, you would still need some process that can handle external requests securely... something a webserver is quite good at. Just running it yourself gives you all the freedom you want, and simplifies things by lessening the number of components in your solution.

The updates on your site I'd keep quite basic: commands you want to run can be handled in the request handlers of the webserver by just calling the relevant (`xmlrpclib`) calls. Dynamically updating the page is best done by some AJAX calls I reckon. Based on your story, these updates are easily put in a JSON object, suitable for periodically updating only the relevant segments of your page.

Comment: Thanks for advice, some great tips here. There are a few reasons as why I'd like to use my hosted web server. For one, it allows for a layer of abstraction. Say I have a friend who is interested in controlling the Arduino for fun, I wouldn't need to distribute my IP address to allow for this. Secondly it offers a way to consolidate data. Say that this same friend, after playing with my Arduino remotely for a bit, would like to set up something similar but doesn't have access to a hosted web server. I would be able offer a way for the information to be shared on my hosted site.

Comment: Good enough reason to include the server :). Then just host your interface website there. For communication between the servers you might consider REST then: it is more easy to implement if you don't have access to the battery of libraries Python has. Just link the user interface site to your personal webserver running as a RESTful service ([CherryPy](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html) also supports this, as do of course all major webservers).